# Order of evaluation - does Mathematica evaluate variables before or after substitution?

Tags: evaluation

Let's say I write

```
y = x^2;
x = 10;
z = y + y^2 + y^3
```

Does Mathematica internally evaluate y before or after substituting it into z?  I.e., does Mathematica internally evaluate this as

```
y = x^2 = 100
z = 100 + 100^2 + 100^3 = 1010100
```

or as

```
z = (10^2)^2 + (10^2)^3 + (10^2)^4 = 1010100
```

?  Obviously in this simple case it doesn't really matter, but if y is an expensive function to calculate, then the former order of evaluation could be much faster than the latter.  In general, if I have intermediate variables that are expensive to calculate, will I get a speedup if I exchange the order of the first two lines of code?

Comment: Each symbol can have a value associated with it or not. When you write `y=x^2`, then later on, write `x=10`, then `y` now automatically becomes `100` since it was pointing to `x` before, but now `x` has a value which is `10`. There is no explicit evaluation of `y`. It is done automatically. It is all linked lists. If a symbol `x` has value other than itself, then its value is used automatically when looking up `y`.

Comment: @Nasser this is exactly what OP is asking about. Are dependencies between rules automatically eliminated, or not? It seems that the answer is not, in most cases anyway. This reminds me of another question, but I can't put my finger on it at the moment.

Comment: Aside: Mathematica is holding onto the symbolic definition of y = x^2.  If you clear x the value of y will be x^2 not 100.  If you had defined x=10 first then the value of y would be 100 before and after x is cleared.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Evaluation.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `Trace`:

```
    Trace[y = x^2;
 x = 10;
 z = y + y^2 + y^3]
```

The result is 
[image]

From this result it looks like the second variant takes place.

Have fun!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `x^2` is computed three times.  One way to see it is this:

```
In[1]:= On[]                                                                                                                                     

On::trace: On[] --> Null.

In[2]:= y = x^2                                                                                                                                  

                 2      2
Set::trace: y = x  --> x .

         2
Out[2]= x

In[3]:= x = 10                                                                                                                                   

Set::trace: x = 10 --> 10.

Out[3]= 10

In[4]:= z = y + y^2 + y^3                                                                                                                        

                 2
y::trace: y --> x .

x::trace: x --> 10.

               2       2
Power::trace: x  --> 10 .

                2
Power::trace: 10  --> 100.

                 2
y::trace: y --> x .

x::trace: x --> 10.

               2       2
Power::trace: x  --> 10 .

                2
Power::trace: 10  --> 100.

               2        2
Power::trace: y  --> 100 .

                 2
Power::trace: 100  --> 10000.

                 2
y::trace: y --> x .

x::trace: x --> 10.

               2       2
Power::trace: x  --> 10 .

                2
Power::trace: 10  --> 100.

               3        3
Power::trace: y  --> 100 .

                 3
Power::trace: 100  --> 1000000.

                  2    3
Plus::trace: y + y  + y  --> 100 + 10000 + 1000000.

Plus::trace: 100 + 10000 + 1000000 --> 1010100.

                     2    3
Set::trace: z = y + y  + y  --> z = 1010100.

Set::trace: z = 1010100 --> 1010100.

Out[4]= 1010100

In[5]:= Off[]
```

I find this easier to follow than `Trace` but it produces too much junk in recent versions when run in the front end, so I had to run it in a terminal.

This observation does not imply that the result of `y -> x^2 -> 10^2 -> 100` is not cached!  (I don't know if it is.)

You can re-assign `y` form `x^2 to simply`100`as simply as`y = y` in this case.  Better, you could make it a function and use memoization to cache the result:

```
Clear[y]
y[x_] := y[x] = x^2
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it seems the order *can* matter, at least when using [SetDelayed](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`), which is common for functions.  In that case, if you swapped the first two lines, it would indeed go faster.

One way to see this is with a very inefficient function, which calculates Fibonacci numbers the long way:

```
slowFib[n_] := If[n <= 2, 1, slowFib[n - 1] + slowFib[n - 2]];
```

On my machine, it takes about 3.2 seconds to calculate the 29th Fibonacci number this way:

```
slowFib[29] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {3.23395, 514229}  *)
```

Here is a slow calculation, with the same ordering as your example code.  It takes 9.7 seconds to run the last line, because it is running `slowFib` 3 times to calculate `y1`:

```
y1 = slowFib1[29];
slowFib1 = slowFib;
z1 = y1 + y1 + y1 // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {2.*10^-6, slowFib1[29]}
    {1.*10^-6, slowFib}
    {9.65774, 1542687}  *)
```

Compare this to  a "fast" version with the first 2 lines swapped.  It calculates the value of `slowFib[29]` just once, when it assigns the value to `y2`, so it only does so once, and takes 3.3 seconds total:

```
slowFib2 = slowFib ) // AbsoluteTiming
(y2 = slowFib2[29]) // AbsoluteTiming
(z2 = y2 + y2 + y2) // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {1.*10^-6, slowFib}
    {3.28709, 514229}
    {4.*10^-6, 1542687}  *)
```

What's going on here is that Mathematica only evaluates `slowFib[29]` when it is called.  In the fast code (vesion 2), it gets called once when defining `y2`.  In the slow code (version 1), it gets called thrice, when defining `z1`.

Comment: Indeed, I just tried swapping the order of the definitions in my actual application (much more complicated than the example in the OP) and got a significant speedup.

Comment: If you are only evaluating your functions at a few values, take a look at tip #5 on [this list](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/): write your expensive functions as `f[x_]:=f[x]=…`, so that values get saved as you go.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that memoization applies to OPs question. In a direct test, the order doesn't seem to make much of a  difference in execution time.

[image]